# C# .net how to read property from Web User Control

Tags: controls

I have a Web user control that consists of a dropdownlist which bind to an autoPostBack event when selectedindexchanged. I assign the selected value to a public property.

But when my aspx page try to read that property, I got empty value because the aspx page get executed before web user control(I think). Should web user control be used this way? How come properties in user control get assigned so late in the life cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the page lifecycle are you trying to read the property? Can you post some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Page_Load of my aspx page. I tried to read myWebUserControl.MyProperty when page.IsPostBack. Thanks